# Dynamically creating an object from the product of a variable number of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm trying to create a Variant from a Product and its associations. The following code works if the product has some associated sides, sizes and options but this is not always the case. If any one of those are not provided then #product produces nil.

```
def self.create_from_product_attrs(product_id, sides, sizes, options)
  sides.product(sizes, options).collect do |side, size, option|
    Variant.create(product_side_id: side.id, product_size_id: size.id, product_option_id: option.id, product_id: product_id)
  end
end
```

I have also tried:

```
array = [sides, sizes, options]
array.first.product(*array[1..-1]).map(&:flatten).collect do |side, size, option|
  Variant.create(product_side_id: side.id, product_size_id: size.id, product_option_id: option.id, product_id: product_id)
end
```

in an attempt to exclude any empty values being passed to #product.

I have had more success with the following but its still failing some tests:

```
array = [sides, sizes, options]
array.reject! { |c| c.empty? }
if array.empty?
  Variant.create(product_id: product_id)
else
  array.first.product(*array.drop(1)).map(&:flatten).collect do |side, size, option|
    variant = Variant.new
    variant.assign_attributes(product_side_id: side.id) if side.present?
    variant.assign_attributes(product_size_id: size.id) if size.present?
    variant.assign_attributes(product_option_id: option.id) if option.present?
    variant.assign_attributes(product_id: product_id)
    variant.save
  end
end
```

Updated to include Rspec tests:

```
before do
    @product_side = Fabricate(:product_side)
    @product_side_2 = Fabricate(:product_side, name: '2 Sides')
    @product_size = Fabricate(:product_size)
    @product_size_2 = Fabricate(:product_size, name: 'A3')
end

it "should create a product variant when the product is created" do
    @product = Fabricate(:product)
    @product.variants.count.should == 1
end

it "should create 2 variants for a product with 2 sides" do
    @product = Fabricate(:product, product_side_ids: ["#{@product_side.id}", "#{@product_side_2.id}"])
    @product.variants.count.should == 2
end

it "should create 2 variants for a product with 2 sizes" do
    @product = Fabricate(:product, product_size_ids: ["#{@product_size.id}", "#{@product_size_2.id}"])
    @product.variants.count.should == 2
end

it "should create 2 variants for a product with 2 options" do
    @product = Fabricate.build(:product)
    @product_option = Fabricate(:product_option, product_id: @product.id)
    @product_option_2 = Fabricate(:product_option, name: 'None', product_id: @product.id)
    @product.save

    @product.variants.count.should == 2
end

it "should create 4 variants for a product with 2 sides and 2 options" do
    @product = Fabricate.build(:product, product_side_ids: ["#{@product_side.id}", "#{@product_side_2.id}"])
    @product_option = Fabricate(:product_option, product_id: @product.id)
    @product_option_2 = Fabricate(:product_option, name: 'None', product_id: @product.id)
    @product.save

    @product.variants.count.should == 4
end

it "should create 8 variants for a product with 2 sides and 2 options and 2 sizes" do
    @product = Fabricate(:product, product_side_ids: ["#{@product_side.id}", "#{@product_side_2.id}"], product_size_ids: ["#{@product_size.id}", "#{@product_size_2.id}"])
    @product_option = @product.product_options.create(name: 'Rounded', description: 'Add a round edge')
    @product_option_2 = @product.product_options.create(name: 'None', description: 'Nothing')
    @product.save
    @product.variants.count.should == 8
end
```

Comment: What does `product(sizes, options)` do - how is it defined?

Comment: It produces a combination off all the arrays it is given.

It is defined by Ruby.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is build an array with a `nil` element for each empty set, and iterate over the sets.  Instead of assigning the id, just assign the object directly (which should work just as well in ActiveRecord).

```
def self.create_from_product_attrs(product_id, sides, sizes, options)
  sides = [nil] if sides.blank?
  sizes = [nil] if sizes.blank?
  options = [nil] if options.blank?
  sides.product(sizes, options).each do |side, size, option|
    Variant.create(product_id: product_id, product_side: side, product_size: size, product_option: option)
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not work if one or more of the associations is nil. For example a Product with 2 sides should return 2 variants but returns 0.

Comment: @Jack - updated to handle a case of passing an empty collection (even if not `nil`) for any of the attribute sets. Does this work for you?

Comment: 3 of the 6 tests I have written now pass, I have edited the question to include the tests.

Comment: @Jack - where are your specs calling `create_from_product_attrs`?  There seems to be some code missing from your description...

Comment: It is being called from an on_create callback from the Product model.

Comment: @Jack - your last 3 specs are faulty.  Two of them call @product.id before the product has ever been saved (generated via `Fabricate.build`) and they don't have an id at that point.  And in the last spec, the options aren't going to be included in the after_create callback, because the product_options are being created after the product was created.